# How can I add a column with a Boolean expression in a Group By query in SQL?

Tags: sql, group-by, hierarchy, self-join

I have the following table that has a product with different materials:

| Product | Material |
| --- | --- |
| Widget 1 | Green |
| Widget 1 | Blue |
| Widget 1 | Red |
| Widget 2 | Orange |
| Widget 2 | Brown |
| Widget 2 | Pink |
| Widget 2 | Black |

I want to create a table that groups by Product and has an additional column that checks if the Material Black is in the Product, as follows:

| Product | Contains_Black |
| --- | --- |
| Widget 1 | 0 |
| Widget 2 | 1 |

How can I create this query, currently I am trying to do a self join but the error 'tables are not allowed in this context' is shown.

This is the code I am trying to run:

```
select
    A.Product,
    case
        when exists (
            select B.Product
            from Table1 as B
            where B.Material = 'Black'
        ) then 1
        else 0
    end as Contains_Black
from Table1 as A
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need a conditional aggregate:

```
select product, Max(case when material = 'Black' then 1 else 0 end) as ContainsBlack
from t
group by product;
```